# Training two NN simultaneously

Tags: keras

Is it possible to train two different NN simultaneously, where the output of the first NN is partially the input for the second NN?

Or have more input values in a deeper layer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The functional API allows you connect multiple models with ease.

Comment: Is it also possible to pre train just one of the NN and then train the combined models together with another data set?

Comment: Yes. Just use the output tensor of your pretrained model as input to your second NN.